# How to handle models when programmatically creating endpoints in FastAPI

Tags: python, mypy, fastapi

The following examples both work just fine, the only issue is that mypy is complaing about `create_operation`.
Specifically I'm getting these errors:

- `Variable "model" is not valid as a type`
- `model? has no attribute "dict"`

Especially the second error doesn't make sense to me since `pydantic.BaseModel` definitely *has* a `dict` method. Is there a better way to annotate this?

```python
from typing import Type
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI, testclient

app = FastAPI()
client = testclient.TestClient(app)


class A(BaseModel):
    foo: str


# regular way of creating an endpoint
@app.post("/foo")
def post(data: A):
    assert data.dict() == {"foo": "1"}


# creating an endpoint programmatically
def create_operation(model: Type[BaseModel]):
     @app.post("/bar")
     def post(data: model):
         assert data.dict() == {"foo": "1"}


create_operation(A)

assert client.post("/foo", json={"foo": 1}).status_code == 200
assert client.post("/bar", json={"foo": 1}).status_code == 200
```

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the type of the model of the endpoint. On personal level, what does the `from typing import Type` do? I've never seen it and I'm curious. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the problem. The question is how to solve it. For `typing.Type` see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)

Comment: Ooo I see. Then I guess that the problem is `Type[BaseModel]` because `BaseModel` should be some sort of abstract class, while `fastapi` under hood needs to get a dictionary representation of the class in order to validate it. Could you try creating a new class that inherits from `Basemodel` and is used as base class for the others as type of the function parameter?

Comment: As I said, the code runs just fine and without errors. It's just that when I check it with mypy I'm having troubles. In fact in the actual code I'm using, it *is* a subclass of `pydantic.BaseModel`. That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I understand that, but since mypy checks at compile time, my guess is that it expects a certain type as parameter, which does not happen. At runtime, python does not complain because it doesn't assume any type, but mypy does, so it complains

Comment: Variables with type `Type[...]` [cannot be used](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases) for annotations from `mypy` point of view.

Comment: I know they can't, but `Type[BaseModel]` is in fact the correct annotation for the function. It's just that FastAPI only allows the definition of the body parameter in this type annotation way.

Comment: You can use a Generic type.